# Is it possible to vectorize the optimize() function in R and if so how?

Tags: r, optimization

I have some code which I am trying to speed up. There is a bottle neck inside a function called by  optimize(). I would like to pass into optimize() vectors of parameters where optim runs for each element of the vector. Does this make sense, can it be done and if so how?

I should also point out that one of the optimize bottlenecks I am referring to in this question is illustrated inside optimbreach, although I would love to know anything that I am doing that is inefficient. The main function to call initially is plotresults().
rundisplay() and displayProbEff() aren't important and won't be called when running plotresults().

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(rgl)

plotresults = function()

{

r_start = 0.5
r_end = 1
r_step = 0.1
nsteps = (r_end-r_start)/r_step+1

riskstart = 0.01
riskend = 1
risksteps = 0.005

plotcols=NULL

for(i in 1:((r_end-r_start)/r_step+1))
  {
  plotcols = c(plotcols, rep(i, (riskend-riskstart)/risksteps+1))
  }

risk=NULL
rout=NULL
foregone=NULL
colour = 

for (r in seq(r_start,r_end,r_step))
  {
  output = species2(r, riskstart, riskend, risksteps)
  risk = c(risk, output$risk)
  rout = c(rout,rep(r, length(output$risk)))
  foregone = c(foregone, output$foregone)   
  #]mod = lm(results$foregone ~ poly(results$risk, 3))  
  }
r= rout  

plot3d(risk, r, foregone, col=plotcols, size=3)
}

species2 = function(r, riskstart,riskend,risksteps)

{
  #set how many years to run the model for when testing risk
  nYears = 3

  #setup the variables for risk values

  #init outputs
  #effort=NULL
  catch=numeric((riskend-riskstart)/risksteps)

  #read in the parameters for the 2 species
  SpeciesParams = as.matrix(read.csv("C:/Documents and Settings/localuser/My Documents/DefineIt/Code/R/speciesparams.csv", sep=",", header=T))

  # set the species parameter for species B to r (this enables us to get results for a range of r's
  SpeciesParams[2,4]=r

  #Calc optimum catch for species A
  maxcatch = optimcatch(SpeciesParams[1,])[[2]]

  #Create vector for risk
  risk = seq(riskstart, riskend, risksteps)

  i=1
    #browser() 
  #Determine the level of effort that subjects species B to a given level of risk
  for(risk in seq(riskstart,riskend,risksteps))
    {
    #calc the effort that would subject vulnerable species (B) to each level of risk
    effort=optimbreach(nYears,risk, SpeciesParams[2,])[[1]]

    #calc the catch of target species (A) for effort calculated in previous line
    catch[i]=maxcatch-meancatch(effort, SpeciesParams[1,])

    #if(catch[length(catch)]>200){browser()}
    i=i+1
    }

    #plot(x=seq(riskstart,riskend,risksteps), y=catch, xlab = "risk", ylab="Foregone Yield")
    output = list(risk=seq(riskstart,riskend,risksteps), foregone=catch)
    return (output)



}


RunDisplay = function(nTimeSteps, e) # e=effort, nTimeSteps=number of timesteps per run
#Runs the model and outputs the biomass and catches as two timeseries plots
  {

  output = RunModelnTimeSteps(nTimeSteps, stddevr_global, r_global, Init_B_global, k_global, q_global, e, 0)

  split.screen(c(1,2))
  screen(1)
  plot(output[[2]], ylim=c(0,k_global), type="l", ylab="Biomass", xlab="Timestep")
  screen(2)
  plot(output[[3]], ylim=c(0,k_global), type="l", ylab="Catch", xlab="TimeStep")

  }

displayProbEff = function()
#A simple subroutine that graphs the change in probability of breaching Bpa for different efforts
  {

  prob_lessBpa = NULL
  for(x in seq(0,2,0.02))
    {
    prob_lessBpa=c(prob_lessBpa,calcprob(x,3,Bpa_global))
    }
  plot(x=seq(0,2,0.02), y=prob_lessBpa, ylab="Probability", xlab="Effort")

  }

optimbreach = function(nTimeSteps, opt_prob, spec_params)
#Calculates the level of effort that meets management objective
#nTimeSteps is length of time to run simulation while checking not falling beneath Bpa
#opt_prob is the maximum probability of going beneath Bpa in a given time period (see previous line)
#that is acceptable by the management objective

  {

  diffprob = function(e, params, spec_params)
    {
    nTimeSteps=params[1]
    opt_prob=params[2]
    prob_breach = calcprob(e, nTimeSteps, spec_params)
    (prob_breach-opt_prob)^2
    }


  params=c(nTimeSteps, opt_prob)  
  a=optimise(diffprob, c(0,1.5), params, spec_params, maximum=FALSE)
  #browser()
  a

  }

optimcatch = function(species_params)
#Calculates the effort that gives the optimum catch
  {

  optimise(meancatch, c(0,2), species_params, maximum=TRUE)

  }

meancatch = function(ef, species_params)
  {
  output=RunModelnTimeSteps(nTimeSteps=1000, species_params, ef)  
  mean(output[[3]])
  }

calcmeans = function(effort)
#Calculates the mean catch and biomass over 1000 timesteps
  {

  output = RunModelnTimeSteps(1000, species_params, e)
  print(paste("Mean Biomass = ", mean(output[[2]])))
  print(paste("Mean Catch = ", mean(output[[3]])))

  }

RunModelnTimeSteps = function(nTimeSteps, sparams, e)
#Runs the surplus production model for nTimeSteps
  {
  #indexes in sparams for various parameters
  #Bpa = 2
  #sd_ = 3
  #r = 4
  #B = 5
  #k = 6
  #q_ = 7 

  P = 0                         #initial production

  Breached = FALSE              #This records whether the biomass fell beneath Bpa
  Biomass = numeric(nTimeSteps)                #biomass
  Catch = numeric(nTimeSteps)          #catch

  Biomass[1]=sparams[5]
  Catch[1]=2

  for (x in 2:nTimeSteps)
    {
    ModOutput = RunTimeStep(sparams[3], sparams[4], Biomass[x-1], sparams[6], sparams[7], e)  #Run the model for 1 timestep

    Biomass[x] = ModOutput[1]  #Get the biomass at end of timestep

    Catch[x] = ModOutput[2]  #Get the catch for this timestep
    #print(Biomass[x])
    #print(sparams[2])
    if (Biomass[x]<=sparams[2])  #Check if biomass has fallen beneath Bpa
      {                            
      Breached=TRUE
      if(Biomass[x]<0){Biomass[x]=0}
      }      
    }
  #if(Bpa==600){browser()   }
  list(Breached, Biomass, Catch)

  }


RunTimeStep = function(sd_, r, B, k, q_, e)
#Calculates one timestep of the model
#outputs the biomass[1] at the end of the timestep and catches[2] through timestep
  {

  change_r = rnorm(n=1, mean=0, sd=sd_) #random change in r
  P = (r + change_r) * B * (1-B/k)  #calc production
  Catch = q_ * e * B  #calc catch
  B = B + P - q_*e*B  #calc results biomass
  c(B,Catch)  #output biomass at end of timestep and catch

  }


calcprob = function(e, nTimeSteps, species_params) # e=effort, Bpa=precautionary biomass limit, nTimeSteps=number of timesteps per run
#Calculates the probability of going beneath Bpa within nTimeSteps
  {

  nIterations = 200            #number of times the simulation is run
  nFails = 0                    #Counts the number of times the biomass goes benath Bpa

  nFails = RunModelnTimeSteps2(nTimeSteps, species_params, e, nIterations)

  nFails/nIterations

  }


RunModelnTimeSteps2 = function(nTimeSteps, sparams, e, nIterations)
#Runs the surplus production model for nTimeSteps
  {
  #indexes in sparams for various parameters
  #Bpa = 2
  #sd_ = 3
  #r = 4
  #B = 5
  #k = 6
  #q_ = 7 

  P = 0                         #initial production

  Breached = rep(F,nIterations)              #This records whether the biomass fell beneath Bpa
  Biomass = matrix(nrow=nTimeSteps, ncol=nIterations)                #biomass
  Catch = matrix(nrow=nTimeSteps, ncol=nIterations)          #catch
  randomvalues = matrix(rnorm(nTimeSteps*nIterations,0,sparams[3]),ncol=nIterations)

  Biomass[1,]=sparams[5]
  Catch[1,]=2

  #ModOutput = RunTimeStep2(sparams[3], sparams[4], Biomass[x-1,], sparams[6], sparams[7], e)

  for (x in 2:nTimeSteps)
    {
    #ModOutput = RunTimeStep2(sparams[3], sparams[4], Biomass[x-1,], sparams[6], sparams[7], e) #Run the model for 1 timestep

    P = (sparams[4] + randomvalues[x,]) * Biomass[x-1] * (1-Biomass[x-1]/sparams[6])  #calc production
    Catch[x,] = sparams[7] * e * Biomass[x-1]
    Biomass[x,] = Biomass[x-1,] + P - Catch[x,]

    Breached = ifelse (Biomass[x,]<=sparams[2], T, Breached)
    ifelse (Biomass[x,]<0,0,Biomass[x,]) 

    }

  #if(Bpa==600){browser()   }

  sum(Breached)
  }
```

Comment: hey there, I don't know if that's possible or not, but just to alert you that `optimize()` and `optim()` are 2 different functions, so you should make your question and the title consistent.

Comment: btw if it's not possible, then you could get some speed up by using the `parallel` package or similar.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I've added the code and changed the function to optimize(). This is only my second post so please bare with me! All help appreciated.

Comment: Wow that's huge! I mean, always neat to see what other people are up to... will give it a glance, BUT ONLY because I'm waiting for a simulation to end, otherwise I'd just wish you good luck.

Comment: ... man that thing's like a whole package! post some example parameters please. You read in a csv. no data no testing. I'm going to log into chat- find me there

Comment: Sorry I missed you. What is the best way to add a file like the .csv? I should also point out that one of the optimize bottlenecks I am referring to in this question is illustrated inside optimbreach, although I would love to know anything that I am doing that is inefficient.

Comment: hm, if it's big then post you data somewhere on the web and give a link. If it's small, or if just a few lines of the data are necessary to figure this out, then use `dput(object)` for necessary arguments (or portions of them).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way you can get speed gains using `parallel`, but it's not vectorization. If you posted some code, then folks might notice other ways to speed it up. Just rework your code to be able to feed it to one of the parallel apply functions, like this:

```
    # some data:
    set.seed(1)
    a <- 1:100
    b <- rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 2) + runif(100, 3, 4) * a

    # some starts:
    pars <- c(a = 1, b = 1)

    # a function to optimize
    FunctionToOptimize <- function(pars, a, b){
        sum(((pars[[1]] + pars[[2]] * a) - b) ^ 2)
    }

    optim(pars,FunctionToOptimize,a = a, b = b)$par

    # and in parallel?
    # a matrix holding your parameters:
    parsMat <- matrix(sample(2:5, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 2, nrow = 50)

    # a function that includes a call to optim()
    FunctionToOptimizePar <- function(Pars, a, b){

        FunctionToOptimize <- function(pars, a, b){
            sum(((pars[[1]] + pars[[2]] * a) - b) ^ 2)
        } 

        optim(Pars, FunctionToOptimize, a = a, b = b)$par
    }

    library(parallel)
    # (I just have 2 cores)
    cl <- makeCluster(2)
    # will spit out the optimized parameters in the same order as given in parsMat
    someresults <- matrix(parRapply(cl, parsMat, FunctionToOptimizePar, a = a, b = b), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
    stopCluster(cl)

    head(someresults)
```