# R Optimize Vectorization

Tags: r, optimization

I have written a function bs.pp that calculates the Black Scholes value of a Put Option.

```
bs.pp <- function (Price, Strike, sigma, texp, int) {
  d1=(1 / (sigma*sqrt(texp)))*(log(Price/Strike)+(int+(sigma^2)/2)*texp)
  d2=d1-sigma*sqrt(texp)
  Strike*pnorm(-d2)*exp(-int*texp)-Price*pnorm(-d1)}
```

Which seems to work well

```
> bs.pp(1000,1000,.2,1,.02)
[1] 69.35905
> bs.pp(1000,900,.25,1,.02)
[1] 46.15609
```

With some help with some people here I have also completed my inverse function, that given (Price, Strike, texp, int) and the result of bs.pp will tell you what the missing sigma value should be.

```
bs.piv <- function(Price, Strike, texp, intr, PutPrice)
{
  optfunc <- function(P, S, sigma, t, i, PP){(bs.pp(Price, Strike, sigma, texp, intr) - PutPrice)^2}
  xmin <- optimize(optfunc, interval = c(0,2), tol = 0.0001, P=Price, S=Strike, t=texp, i=intr, PP=PutPrice)
  xmin$minimum
}
```

Which also works well

```
> bs.piv(1000,1000,1,.02,69.35)
[1] 0.1999901
> bs.piv(1000,900,1,.02,30.25)
[1] 0.2000281
```

The problem is that while the first function, bs.pp is vectorized

```
> bs_strike <- c(1000,900)
> bs.pp(1000,bs_strike,.2,1,.02)
[1] 69.35905 30.24388
```

Unfortunately the second inverse function returns errors

```
> bs_pp_ans <- c(69.35, 30.25)
> bs.piv(1000,bs_strike,1,.02,bs_pp_ans)
Error in optimize(optfunc, interval = c(0, 2), tol = 1e-04, P = Price,  : 
  invalid function value in 'optimize'
```

Comment: `Vectorize(bs.piv)(1000,bs_strike,1,.02,bs_pp_ans)`

Comment: Thanks. In case it wasn't obvious I'm pretty new to R. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @user20650: You should post your solution as an answer since it solved the OP's problem.

Comment: @AlexA.; fair enough, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade comment.

I don't think you can vectorise your code due to the `optimize()` function ... [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515071/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-the-optimize-function-in-r-and-if-so-how). However, as an alternative, you can use the `Vectorize()` function. Rather than a true vectorised solution (in terms of vector in / vector out at a low(ish) level) it is a wrapper for various other functions. (To see the code of `Vectorize` just enter it into the terminal).

So you can change your code to

```
Vectorize(bs.piv)(1000,bs_strike,1,.02,bs_pp_ans)
```